# Wordpress/PHP call to undefined function error

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I get a `call to undefined function` error but can't see why.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function stringReplace() in ...z

```
 public function stringReplace($newName){
    strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $newName)));
}

public function add(){
    add_meta_box(
        stringReplace($this->CMB_Name),
        __( $this->CMB_Name, 'plugin' ),
        array( $this, 'display' ),
        'page',
        'normal',
        'low'
    );
}
```

The idea is to replace text. I don't want to repeat myself a couple of times for every instance it is placed.
So the function should change that.

What am I missing?

Comment: It should be `$this->stringReplace` instead of just calling `stringReplace`.

Comment: @nickb That was it. Big Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stringReplace` is not a function. It is a *class method*. You must refer to it using the `$this` keyword:

```
public function add(){
    add_meta_box(
        $this->stringReplace($this->CMB_Name),
        __( $this->CMB_Name, 'plugin' ),
        array( $this, 'display' ),
        'page',
        'normal',
        'low'
    );
}
```